# use checkbox to hide/unhide rows based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

Using VBA in excel, trying to understand how I can use a checkbox to hide/unhide any row that has a specific value in a specific column. My VBA skills are getting better more I practice but I am still not good with loops just yet. Appreciate any help you can provide. Here is what I have so far.

```
Private Sub CkBx_ShowAllRecords_Click()
If Me.CkBx_ShowAllRecords = True Then
 For Each Row In Range("Table1").ListObject.ListColumns
    If Row.Cells(1, "column5").Value = "Submission Complete" Then
    Application.EntireRow.Visible=True
Next
End if
End Sub
```

Additionally when I uncheck the box I would want all rows where column 5 cell value equals "submission complete" would be hidden (just the opposite of what I put above when I check the box control).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this may help you:

```
Private Sub CkBx_ShowAllRecords_Click()
Dim i As Long
If Me.CkBx_ShowAllRecords = True Then
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Rows.Count
        If ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(i, 5).Value = "Submission Complete" Then
            Rows((i + 1) & ":" & (i + 1)).Select
            Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next i
Else
    ActiveSheet.Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help on this. The code kind of worked but I realized I was thinking about this situation all wrong so I apologise if I wasted your time. I ended up applying code for an auto filter rather than looping through each line of the table. I can't believe I didn't think of it that way sooner.